# Connection is not secure - MOZILLA_PKIX_ERROR_SELF_SIGNED_CERT

Tags: laravel, mozilla

I am creating Laravel app and I am using XAMPP. To hide root directory when I access localhost and go inside Laravel project folder I added to httpd-vhosts.conf:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "C:/xampp/htdocs"
    ServerName localhost
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "C:/xampp/htdocs/lsapp/public"
    ServerName lsapp.dev
</VirtualHost>
```

And to file in `C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts` I added:

```
127.0.0.1 localhost
127.0.0.1 lsapp.dev
```

Now when I access page with lsapp.dev in Mozilla or Chrome I get this error:

> lsapp.dev uses an invalid security certificate. The certificate is not
>   trusted because it is self-signed. The certificate is only valid for .
>   Error code: MOZILLA_PKIX_ERROR_SELF_SIGNED_CERT

On Edge it works fine but it's annoying to switch pages. And there is no option like usually where you accept risk and add exception. So how can I work around that or perhaps other way to hide Laravel root directory?

Comment: Either add your self-signed certificate to the trusted certificates of your system/browser or just don't bother with SSL for local development.

Answer (score 4):

Solution that worked for me was not to use .dev so I replaced it with .test. Chromium forced all domains with the .dev TLD to only respond to secure connections

Comment: It's the same solution for symfony 4. It should be changed by .test and it works. More details: https://superuser.com/q/1303396/967702

Comment: Thanks. After hours of frustration I finally found this solution! My browser is Firefox 104.0.2 on Ubuntu 22.04 LTS